# Как в Python PIL сделать обводку фотографии

Tags: python, pil, pillow

Как сделать обводку на фотографии, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
img = Image.open('myphoto.jpg')
img_border = ImageOps.expand(img, border=100, fill='black')
img_border.save('myphoto_border.jpg')
```